# Move filtered data extension into Salesforce data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a filtered data extension (via a filter activity) inside MC, our MC instance has Marketing Cloud connector which creates a "Salesforce Data Extensions" folder.

I cannot move my filtered DE in there, can anyone explain why?

EDIT: The source data extension is a synchronised DE.

Comment: That's strange, I've just tested on my side and it works fine..

Comment: Same here. Did a quick test and was able to move a filtered DE to Salesforce Data Extensions. Tested with both standard and synchronized DEs.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but the source DE is a synchronised DE.

Comment: yep, tried that and worked as well for me @DeploymentFailure

Comment: @zuzannamj Did you move this through Email Studio or Contact Builder?

Comment: @DeploymentFailure I used Email Studio, I find Contact Builder buggy

Comment: Actually, it seems that Salesforce data extensions folder is not even visible on Contact Builder. Did you try using Email Studio?

Comment: So the DE originally sat in Sync'd DE's. From email studio I am only shown the Sync'd DE folder. If I navigate to Contact Builder, I can move to Sync'd DE and Data Extensions folder, but Salesforce Data Extension folder is not visible in both.